# How to set mongoose plugin to a schema after creating NestFactory

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-plugins

I'm using [nest](https://nestjs.com/), I need to call another service to get a key before setting a mongoose plugin, I tried to init the mongoose plugin in `main.ts`, but it doesn't work, below is what I did

- test.schema.ts

```html
  import { Document } from 'mongoose';
            
    export class TestSchema extends Document{
           readonly test: String;
    }
```

- init.schema.ts

```html
    export const initMongoosePlugin = () => {
    
      TestSchema.plugin(plugin, {
        fields: ['test'],
        secret: global['KEY'], // init it in main.ts
      });
    
    };
```

- main.ts

```html
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const appService: AppService = app.get(AppService);
  global['KEY'] = await appService.getKey();
  // init Mongoose Plugin
  initMongoosePlugin();
  app.use(requestIp.mw());
  await app.listen(3000));
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: Are you using `MongooseModule` from `Nest`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MongooseModule from @nestjs/mongoose

Comment: then when main.ts runs, the MongooseModule has been initialized with all of its models (forFeature), you can use app.get to grab the Model you need then get the schema out of the model then set the plugin on the schema

Comment: Seems great! could you answer this question with some sample codes?

Comment: I’ll try to put something together

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#defining looks like it's not going to work.

Answer (score -1):

Do you get error or it is just not set? Have you tried to call it from the service constructor in which you inject the schema?
However I use the following to define a schema in mongodb

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

export const TestSchema = new Schema(
    {
      test: String;
    }
);
```